# "Add To favorites" does not works with appImages

Tags: appimage, favorites

I noticed that applications distributed as 'appimage' when run, they did not present the "add to favorites" in the command bar, when you right click on the icon. Why? Is there an alternative? Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Please provide OS/release details, and it may help if you provide an example of an appimage program providing an "*add to favorites*" option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to be able to "pin" any application, including an appimage, as a favorite, it needs to have a permanently installed launcher. A launcher is a text file with `.desktop` extension, placed in specific locations (`~.local/share/applications`, `/usr/share/applications` and others), that contains instructions for your desktop environment on how to run the application, what icon to use, etc.

Many appimages contain their own `.desktop` file and icons inside the `.AppImage` file. You typically need to edit so it correctly points to your appimage. Place it in the folder `.local/share/applications`, so it automatically will appear in Application overview. Alternatively, [create your own `.desktop`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand) file. A few appimages may automatically install a launcher on first run.

*Finding and using `.desktop` file and icon provided by the application*

In many cases, the appimage provides a `.desktop` file and icons. That will be included in the `.AppImage` file. That `.AppImage` file contains a file system that is mounted when the application is running.

To find these files, run the AppImage. This will cause the AppImage to be mounted in your file system. You can then access the application's files with your file manager.

For example:

‣ Run the AppImage. I take `OpenShot-v2.5.1-x86_64.AppImage` as an example.

‣ Run the `mount` command to see where the AppImage is mounted. For Openshot, I see

```
OpenShot-v2.5.1-x86_64.AppImage on /tmp/.mount_v87XIC type fuse.OpenShot-v2.5.1-x86_64.AppImage (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=1000,group_id=1000)
```

in the output of `mount`.

‣ Navigate in your file manager to, in this example, `/tmp/.mount_v87XIC`.

- We find a `org.openshot.OpenShot.desktop` that we can copy and eventually edit to use as a launcher.
- We find an Openshot icon (`/tmp/.mount_v87XIC/usr/bin/openshot-qt.svg`), that we can copy to `~/.local/share/icons` to use as a sharp, scalable icon.